# c# talk to Ethernet card drivers

Tags: c#

Hello i am a beginner at c# and i wanna program a windows application that will get data from user and send to Ethernet card drivers in order to transmit them wireless

Comment: Why does it need to go to the drivers? C# is usually more high-level than that. You can send data to other computers and it doesn't matter if you go over the wire or wireless.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you *don't* actually want to fiddle with the network card!

Take a look at the [System.Net.Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx) namespace.  TcpClient and TcpListener are the cornerstone of straightforward network communications in the .Net Framework.